# How do I animate a graph created in VBA using arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, charts, jquery-animate

I have a written a code which updates a scatter chart in vba using arrays.My objective is to do everything in vba outside excel. I do start the the program from excel by clicking a button. I am able to change and update the graph at given time intervals. But I can't see the graph evolve, i.e. I can't see the graph until the VBA-script is finished. How can I make the graph alive while the program is running. My final objective is to scrape data from a website every 15th second, do some calculations and display how it evolves in a graph.

```
Sub test3()
Dim C As Chart
Dim s As Series
Dim myData, A, B, D As Variant
ReDim A(50, 1), B(50, 1), D(50, 1)
Set C = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With C
    Set s = C.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Set v = C.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    C.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
End With
x = Timer()
xxx = x
While xx - x < 30
    xx = Timer()
    If xx - xxx > 2 Then
        i = i + 1
        A(i, 1) = 0.6 * i
        B(i, 1) = xx - x
        D(i, 1) = i ^ 0.5
        myData = A '
        myData1 = B '
        myData2 = D
    With C
        Set s = C.SeriesCollection(1)
        s.XValues = myData1
        s.Values = myData
        Set v = C.SeriesCollection(2)
        v.XValues = myData1
        v.Values = myData2
    End With
    xxx = Timer()
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be good to use `DoEvents`, but without sharing the code it is not possible to receive an answer telling you where...

Comment: I have pasted the code. Sorry if you find it amateuristic but that's what I am.

Comment: I do not see any code... Did you edit your question and add the code? You maybe forgot to save the changes...

Comment: Sorry I am new to this site. I will go back to my question and paste the code. I should add that I have done nice animated graphics by keeping the data in Excel sheets. But I just wanted to take it one step further.

Comment: No problem. Everybody was new sometime...

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, it will be good to properly declare **all** used variables:

```
Dim C As Chart
Dim s As Series, v As Series, x As Double, xx As Double, xxx As Double
Dim myData, myData1, myData2, A, B, D As Variant, i As Long
```

Please, take care that `myData, myData1, myData2, A, B` are of `Variant` type because Excel does that if you do not specify anything about the type. Not due the fact that the enumeration ends with `D As Variant`. I mean, in the next example declaration

```
Dim x, y, z As Long
```

Only `z` is a `Long` type. `x` and `y` is 'Variant` type...

2. Then, insert `DoEvents` after `xx = Timer()`:

```
'...
'your code...
    xx = Timer()
    DoEvents
'your code...
'...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and taking the time. I will try it out and follow your advice. I code VBA very sporadically so my code is very sloppy and amateuristic. Once again, thank you.

Comment: @Dantes: Glad I could help! But when somebody give us a solution, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the solution works... :)